# QWidget move() and QGraphicsOpacityEffect causing black border

Tags: c++, qt

This took me awhile to figure out... but whenever I try to use a QWidget's move() (or even setGeometry) function that has a child QWidgit with a QGraphicsOpacityEffect assigned to it, it causes the QWidgit to have a black border along the right and bottom sides.

The border is exactly the size of the amount of pixels that I moved. If I increase the amount I move the widget, the border increases also...

If I remove the move() call, the problem is fixed... If I use 0.99 instead of 1.0 in the setOpacity() call, it fixes the problem...

Here's a picture of the issue...
[image: https://i.imgur.com/LLI62Fu.png]

Does anyone know how to avoid/fix this...?

Here's my code.

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>560</width>
    <height>351</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="TestHolder2" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>200</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>120</width>
      <height>80</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    ui->TestHolder2->resize(450, 250);
    ui->TestHolder2->move(11, 11);
    ui->TestHolder2->setStyleSheet("background-color: black;");

    QWidget* new_widget = new QWidget(ui->TestHolder2);
    new_widget->setStyleSheet("background-color:red;");
    new_widget->resize(450, 250);

    QGraphicsOpacityEffect* opacity_effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(new_widget);
    new_widget->setGraphicsEffect(opacity_effect);
    opacity_effect->setOpacity(1);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/VuJnhXC in Linux with Qt 5.10.1

Comment: @eyllanesc strange that is not at all what I get on Windows 7. Right now I have the setOpacity() set to opacity_effect->setOpacity(0.99). Which fixes the issue, but it's a pretty stupid fix.

Comment: It's a bug for me, report it.

Comment: I think so too @eyllanesc. As always, thanks!

Comment: _When changing the position, the widget, if visible, receives a move event (moveEvent()) immediately. If the widget is not currently visible, it is guaranteed to receive an event before it is shown._ maybe related.

Comment: A temp solution of the bug, reimplement the `QGraphicsOpacityEffect::setOpacity` if the value equal to 1 then ignore `setOpacity` shall help.

Comment: @Jiu ignoring setOpacity if 1 wouldn't really be useful as the default opacity is 0.7. A better temp solution is to override setOpacity and if 1 is given, call super with 0.99 instead.